# concatenate/append/merge files in c++ (windows) without coping

Tags: c++, windows, file, concatenation

How can i concatenate few large files(total size~ 3 Tb) in 1 file using c/c++ on windows?
I **cant** copy data, because it takes too much time, so i cant use:

- cmd copy
- Appending One File to Another File(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- and so on(stream::readbuf(),...)

I just need represent few files as one.

Comment: Do you want them to look like one file in *your* program, or to any program?

Comment: @BoPersson to other program. later on im using just filepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is inside your own program only, then  you can create a class that would virtually glue the files together so you can read over it and make it apear as a single file.

if you want to physically have a single file. then no, not possible.
that requires opening file 1 and appending the others.
or creating a new file and appending all the files.
neither the C/C++ library nor the windows API have a means to concatenate files

even if such an API would be available, it would be restrictive in that the first file would have to be of a size that is a multiple of the disk allocation size.
Going really really low level, and assuming the multiple of allocation size is fulfilled... yes, if you unmount the drive, and physically override the file system and mess around with the file system structures, you could "stitch" the files together but that would be a challenge to do for FAT, and near impossible for NTFS.

Comment: ty, I expected something like this.